# How to hide show table as per drop down selection in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

i have created a view in reactjs in which i have one drop down. when page loads for the first time, the drop down value is blank. I user selects any value in drop down then the api hits and get response and show the response in the below table. And If user change the value in the drop down then again the response for other id gets and shows the data in the table. Until this all works fine. But when i select the "Select One" in the drop down which is empty then i want to hide table. this scenario throws error

> "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node."

I have searched a lot but nothing found any good solution which works with my code.

```
handlePartnerChange = e => {   
    e.preventDefault(); 
    let val = e.target.value;
    console.log('val---->',val);
    this.setState({      
      hold_partner_id:val,
      syscoProductLoader:false,

    }, () => {
      if(val != '' && val != null && val != undefined){
        console.log('val is not empty===>', val)
        this.getAllSyscoProductByPartnerId(val);
      }else{
        console.log('val is empty===>', val)       

       this.setState({ syscoProductLists: [], apiError: "Please select the partner to display sysco product" },()=>{
         console.log('this.state---->',this.state);
         //$('#example').DataTable();

       });
      }
     // console.log("this.state----------->", this.state);
    });
  } 

<div className="main-body tableView">
                  {this.state.partnerLoader == true ? (
                    <Loader
                      type="TailSpin"
                      color="black"
                      height={80}
                      width={100}
                      style={{ textAlign: "center" }}
                    />
                  ) : this.state.partnerApiError == "" ? (
                    <div>
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        className="btn btn-darkone rightButton"
                        onClick={() => this.handleSyscoProductModalShowClick("Add", null)}
                      >
                        Add Product
                      </button>
                      <div className="page-header-title roleHeading bottom16">Sysco Product</div>
                      <label className="labelFont">Select Partner</label>
                      <select className="form-control tabelselect" style={{ border: "1px solid #818181" }} name="partnerId" value={this.state.hold_partner_id} onChange={this.handlePartnerChange}>
                        <option value="">Select one</option>
                        {this.state.partnerLists.map(
                          (partnerList, index) => (
                            <option
                              value={partnerList.id}
                              key={partnerList.id}
                            >
                              {partnerList.partner_name}
                            </option>
                          )
                        )}
                      </select>
                      <br />
                      <div>   
                       {/*  {this.state.hold_partner_id == "" ? (<div><b>Please select the partner to display products</b></div>) : ( */}
                            {this.state.syscoProductLoader == true ? (
                              <Loader
                                type="TailSpin"
                                color="black"
                                height={80}
                                width={100}
                                style={{ textAlign: "center" }}
                              />
                            ) :                            
                            this.state.apiError == "" ? (
                              <div>
                               <table
                            id="example"
                            className="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive"
                          >
                            <thead className="tableHeadRow">
                                <tr>  
                                <th style={{ width: "1%" }}>ITEM NO</th>
                                <th style={{ width: "1%" }}>CASE SIZE</th>
                                <th style={{ width: "2%" }}>UOM</th>
                                {/* <th style={{ width: "1%" }} >CATEGORY</th> */}

                               {/*  <th style={{ width: "2%" }} >BRAND</th>
                                <th style={{ width: "1%" }} >PRODUCT</th>
                                <th style={{ width: "1%" }} >PRODUCT REBATE %</th>
                                <th style={{ width: "1%" }} >REBATE</th> */}
                                <th style={{ width: "1%" }} >PRODUCT REBATE $ PER CASE</th>
                                <th
                                  style={{ width: "3%", color: "transparent" }}
                                ></th>
                               </tr>  
                            </thead>
                            <tbody >
                              {this.state.syscoProductLists.map((syscoProductList, index) => (

                                <tr key={syscoProductList.id}>
                                  <td>{syscoProductList.Item_Number}</td>
                                  <td>{syscoProductList.Case_Size}</td>
                                  <td className="text-wrap">{syscoProductList.UOM}</td>
                                  {/* <td className="text-wrap"><p >{syscoProductList.category}</p></td> */}

                                 {/*  <td ><p >{syscoProductList.Brand} </p></td>
                                  <td ><p >{syscoProductList.Product}</p></td>
                                  <td className="text-wrap"><p >{syscoProductList.Rebate_%}</p></td>
                                  <td className="text-wrap"><p >{syscoProductList.rebate_factor}</p></td> */}
                                  <td className="text-wrap"><p >{syscoProductList.Rebate_$_per_case}</p></td>
                                  <td>
                                    <div className="btn-group pull-right roleBtnGroup" >
                                      <a
                                        title="View"
                                        style={{ width: "33%" }}
                                        className="btn btn-mini"
                                        onClick={e => {
                                          this.handleSyscoProductModalShowClick("View", syscoProductList);
                                        }}
                                      >
                                        <span className="mdi mdi-24px mdi-eye iconHover" />
                                      </a>
                                      <a
                                        style={{ width: "100%" }}
                                        className="btn btn-mini"
                                        title="Delete"
                                        onClick={() => this.handleConfirmModalShowClick(syscoProductList.id)}
                                      >
                                        <span className="mdi mdi-24px mdi-trash-can iconHover" />
                                      </a>
                                    </div>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>

                              ))}
                            </tbody>
                            {/* <tfoot>

                            </tfoot> */}
                          </table>
                          </div>
                            ) : (
                              this.state.apiError == 'Please select the partner to display sysco product'?(
                                <div>
                                <b>{this.state.apiError}</b>
                                </div>
                              ):(
                                <div>
                                <b>{this.state.apiError}</b>
                                <br/>
                                <button onClick={this.handleTryAgain}>Try Again</button>
                                </div>
                              )

                            )}
                  {/*   )} */}

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  ) : (
                        <b>{this.state.partnerApiError}</b>
                      )}
                </div>
```

Comment: Use a state variable such as shouldShowTable: false (or true depending on your need). Change/reset state var based on the dropdown selection. Conditionally display the table based on state -> {shouldShowTable && <table>...</table>}

Comment: @ishettyl ok..i'will try nd get you back..thank you for your reply

Comment: still getting the same error @lshettyl

Comment: Sorry, but the code looks pretty unreadable to me! Here is an example of how you can do that - https://codesandbox.io/s/great-clarke-g10w9

Comment: @Ishettyl Thank a lot..the reference link works.